# I want to create a report button, but if I use a callback, I have to re-enter it every time the bot is turned off

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@bot.command()
async def report(ctx):
    button1 = Button(label="user report ", style=discord.ButtonStyle.red, value ="1")
    button2 = Button(label="other", style=discord.ButtonStyle.red)
    button3 = Button(label="ohter ", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)

    view = View()
    view.add_item(button1)
    view.add_item(button2)
    view.add_item(button3)
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f" report", description = "click!", color = 0x3994d4)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed, view=view)
    
async def on_interaction(interaction):
```

I'm not sure how to use on_interaction

I want to create a channel when I press the three report buttons. Also, it would be nice to have a delete channel button on the created channel. I want it to be applied even when the bot is reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you want Views to keep functioning after restarting your bot, you'll have to store the messages somewhere, attach a custom ID to them, and re-load the Views on startup.

There's an official example for persistent views you might want to look at: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/views/persistent.py

> I'm not sure how to use on_interaction

This is an event that gets invoked every time someone triggers an interaction. However, you shouldn't use it for your use-case as it would over-complicate things for no reason. Callbacks suffice.

Your code just creates Views & Buttons inline. It's recommended to subclass `View` (and optionally Button, otherwise use the decorator) which is a lot cleaner. Otherwise you have to monkeypatch the callback in there by overriding the attribute, which is very ugly. Just subclass it. There's multiple examples for that on GitHub as well: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/views/confirm.py

Subclassing will also allow you to very easily re-create the specific View on startup (when you add persistent Views).

Comment: Can I use bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!!', intents=intents) and bot = PersistentViewBot() together?

Comment: ...yes? `PersistentViewBot` is just the name he gave to it, you can name the class `Dave` if you want to, it doesn't matter. The example directly subclasses `commands.Bot`, so it _is_ a `commands.Bot`. You can do everything with it that you can do with your regular `commands.Bot` bot because it _is_ one. The only important part is registering your persistent views in `setup_hook`, there's not much else going on.